# Bottom Sheet doesn't appear sometimes in complicated view

Tags: android, material-design, android-support-library

This GIF pretty much shows what I am talking about:

[image: The Bug in Action]

I have a fairly complicated DrawerLayout -> CoordinatorLayout -> ViewPager -> Fragment -> RecyclerView situation going on in my app.

When a user long clicks on one of the items in the RecyclerView it sends a Broadcast to the ParentActivity which then signals the BottomSheet to appear.

Usually it works fine but every once in a while the BottomSheet doesn't appear. I have a FrameLayout that acts as an overlay between the ParentActivity and the ViewPager. When you click the Overlay it tells the BottomSheet to collapse. You can see in the GIF above, that in situations when the BottomSheet does not appear it still animates on collapse.

This behavior happens pretty frequently on my Nexus 5 Genymotion (API 21) emulator. On real devices it almost never happens, but it does sometimes.

What I have noticed is that if I do the long click and hold until the BottomSheet appears, it always appears. It's when I release immediately after the long click is registered that the BottomSheet might not appear.

I'm fairly certain that this is a situation where the RecyclerView is interfering in some way, but I can't really figure out why or how. Any debugging tips would be appreciated.

For reference here is the layout in question:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/gray"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                        android:background="@color/green"
                        android:elevation="4dp"
                        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
                        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

                    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                        android:id="@+id/budget_display_mode_tabs"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/green"
                        android:elevation="4dp"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        app:tabGravity="fill"
                        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/green"
                        app:tabMode="fixed" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/gray"
                android:orientation="vertical" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/primary_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@null"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progress"
                style="@style/ProgressBar"/>

        </FrameLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/full_screen_overlay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:background="@color/blackLight"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipToPadding="true"
            android:background="@color/gray"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bottom_edit"
                style="@style/BottomSheetButton"
                android:text="@string/option 1"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_list"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left|start"
        android:background="@color/kEDColorGrayLightest" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

`primaryView` and `content` are set to `View.GONE` when the ViewPager is turned on.

This is the receiver that triggers the BottomSheet:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver modifyBudgetItemBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
        fullScreenOverlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
};
```

UPDATE: I have a sub-optimal work around in place. I have BottomSheetBehavior state listener that waits for the BottomSheet to be Expand and it does `bottomSheet.requestLayout()` this causes the sheet to at least appear. The experience is poor though because the sheet appears to 'flicker' in, instead of sliding up. The `requestLayout` work around doesn't seem to produce a flicker on real devices.

Comment: I have the exact same problem.  I have a fragment on a bottom sheet and the UI will not draw no matter what I do.  It definitely seems like a bug in BottomSheet implementation.

Comment: @chubbsondubs Yea this is what I fear. I noticed that it only seems to be happening on certain phones (off the top of my head >= 21 but I'm not totally sure). If I have some time, I am going to setup a barebones example project. If I can cleanly repro it I will submit a bug report to Google/Android.

Answer (score 1):

This is the known issue as dicussed by google developers On some Pre-lollipop devices bottom sheet does not work

I found a solution after R&D for a day. Try this

```
ViewCompat.postOnAnimation(yourCoordinator, new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(yourCoordinator);
            }
        });
```

Put this code after initializing views